# Ionic 2:Handling click on push notification

Tags: cordova, push-notification, ionic2

I'm using ionic [push plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) to handle the push notification that are sent from google  FCM. Below is the code that I'm using for registering and receiving notification.

```
pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
```

If the app is not opened I will get notification on top, if it is opened I will directly get alert(the code that inside subscribe((notification: any) gets executed). Now the problem is,

1. if app is not opened, on click of notification I must be able to trigger some function so that I can extract payload data and perform some action.
2. Even when the app is opened the notification should appear on top and on click of it I must be able to trigger some function.

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved the solution for this. Earlier I was using [Cordova-plugin-firebase](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase/) on the server side and  [PhoneGap-plugin-push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) on the client side. The main reason for using this combination was both were free for any number of notifications. But in PhoneGap-plugin-push I faced many issues, though the authors were answering the queries in the GitHub, it was not immediate. So finally I moved my app to [One-Signal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/). Easy to integrate, best support, completely free and very important the notifications are very reliable. Instructions for using one-signal areas below.

1. Set up the one-signal server side by following the instructions in the below mentioned official link: 
   https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-sdk-setup
2. Install the one-signal plugin to the ionic app with below-mentioned commands.

> ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```

3. Then import { OneSignal } from '@ionic-native/onesignal'; in app.module.ts and register OneSignal in provider.
4. Create a function or add the below code in constructor of app.componet.ts

> this.oneSignal.startInit('YOUR_APPID',
>   'YOUR_GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER_IF_ANDROID');
>
> this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);
>
> ```
> this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
>  // do something when notification is received
> });
>
> this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
>   // do something when a notification is opened
> });
>
> this.oneSignal.endInit();
> ```

5. App id you will get from One-signal dashboard.

   6. Even you will get instructions for getting Google-project-id there (you need it only if you are using Android).

So if anybody looking for an alternative to fire base + phone gap push plugin then [One-Signal](https://onesignal.com/) would be the best choice for you.